# Aerospike how to write records in batches to avoid inconsistency

Tags: aerospike

How we can write a batch function for aerospike that will help us in storing 10 million records and without any data loss. Moreover if the function is called simuntaneously then the data storing should be done in proper way no override should happen and no data loss .

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no batch write API in Aerospike. You have to write each record individually. The only way to never have any data loss is to use Strong Consistency Mode. It covers all sorts of corner cases and ensures committed writes are never lost.